# Is there any way to do this easier?

Tags: java

I'm new to java, i do study from udemy.
My question is...at the end of learning java i will find out there are n better ways to do the same thing ? (i just want to accelerate the process of learning)
There is my code if some one can give me an example of a better way so i can understand. Thank you !!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        toMillesPerHour(50);
        toMillesPerHour(90);
        toMillesPerHour(100);
        toMillesPerHour(130);
        toMillesPerHour(-20);
    }
    public static void toMillesPerHour(double kilomettersPerHour) {
        //return round value
        if(kilomettersPerHour >= 0) {
            kilomettersPerHour = (int) kilomettersPerHour / 1.60934;
            int roundKm = (int) kilomettersPerHour;
            System.out.println("You travel with speed of: " + roundKm +" Miles");
        }else {
            System.out.println("Negative value detected");
        }
    }
```

```
You travel with speed of: 31 Miles
You travel with speed of: 55 Miles
You travel with speed of: 62 Miles
You travel with speed of: 80 Miles
Negative value detected
```

Comment: That's part of the experience. There's no single best way to do most things. There may be several equally valid solutions (and people with differing opinions on which one is supposedly "the best"). Learning software development properly takes years, and there are no shortcuts. As for the code in your question, why do you think it could be improved?

Comment: How about https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ when you do not have errors but strive for improvement?

Comment: This is unfortunately a bad question for a format like StackOverflow. Maybe [CodeReview.SE] would be a better place to ask such a question, but I'm not active there.

Comment: One improvement would be to not reuse kilomettersPerHour for holding miles per hour. It's misleding, and makes reading the code harder. Also, roundKm  actually holds miles, not km .. so call it roundMiles instead.

Comment: Hi Mihai, welcome! This is more for the Code Review group (Stack Exchange group too) than here in the StackOverflow.

Comment: @Brother Not in its current form, although it could be modified into a question fitting the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume a typical Java developer with some experience would do these things:

1. change the return type to `double` (`int` if you need to round the result);
2. throw an exception when `kilomettersPerHour < 0`;
3. print the results in the `main`.

For example,

```
public static double toMillesPerHour(double kilomettersPerHour) {
    if (kilomettersPerHour < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative value detected");
    }

    return kilomettersPerHour / 1.60934;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make the change steven35 suggest, but also in your toMilesPerHour method you shouldn't use the parameter variable to store the result of divison. Instead of that you should do something like:

```
int milesPerHour = (int)kilometersPerHour / 1.60934
```

This way you don't need to make any additional variables to round your result. Also it's bad practice to modify parameter variables.

Answer (score 0):

You could just define the values in an array and iterate over them. Then every time you add a new value, you don't have to call `toMillesPerHour()` again.

```
double[] values = { 50.0, 90.0, 100.0, 130.0, -20.0 };
for (double value : values) {
    toMillesPerHour(value);
}
```

Comment: In this case, you can either leave out the `new int[]` part, or use `new int[] {...}` instead of `values` in the `for`: `for (int value : new int[] {...}) {`.

Comment: Isn't this more readable though? Defining the array in the loop? What if you have a lot of elements?

Comment: Please leave out the `new double[]` part. As in `double[] values = {...}`.

Comment: That's a good suggestion.

Comment: That was the gist of my first comment. `new [] {...}` only makes sense if you want to use it as expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Math.round() for more accurate result.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    toMillesPerHour(50);
    toMillesPerHour(90);
    toMillesPerHour(100);
    toMillesPerHour(130);
    toMillesPerHour(-20);
}
public static void toMillesPerHour(double kilomettersPerHour) {
    //return round value
    if(kilomettersPerHour >= 0) {
        kilomettersPerHour = kilomettersPerHour / 1.60934;
        int roundKm = (int) Math.round( kilomettersPerHour );            
        System.out.println("You travel with speed of: " + roundKm +" Miles");
    }else {
        System.out.println("Negative value detected");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My single biggest issue with this code is that the name `toMilesPerHour(50);` only tells half the story. 50 what? Don't make me look inside to figure that out.

Not convinced? Ok now I need a method that converts feet per second to miles per hour. What am I supposed to name it that won't cause confusion?

If your method was hanging off a type named `KilometersPerHour` this name would be fine but as is this name makes the abstraction fail. I have to look inside to know what it means.

Comment: Just from a simple post i did learn a lot, you are right and it make sense now for me also. Awesome guys !! keep it this way.

Answer (score -1):

1. You could use [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html). - It allows you to remove alot of code.
2. You do not need double.
3. Using parameters as local variables is not so good approach.

Have a look at:

```
class Printer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        toMillesPerHour(50, 90, 100, 130, -20);
    }

    public static void toMillesPerHour(int... kilomettersPerHour) {
        Arrays.stream(kilomettersPerHour).forEach(Printer::printRound);
        //return round value
    }

    private static void printRound(int kmPerHour) {
        String message = (kmPerHour >= 0) ? calculate(kmPerHour) : "Negative value detected";
        System.out.println(message);
    }

    private static String calculate(int kmPerHour) {
        int roundKm = (int) (kmPerHour / 1.60934);
        return "You travel with speed of: " + roundKm + " Miles";
    }
}
```